# Java Tomcat server.xml

Tags: intellij-idea

I installed Tomcat on a laptop and on a computer, everything worked immediately on a computer, but it does not work on a laptop.

On localhost:8080 shows a white page (that is, nothing), if the address is connected through the idea, it gives an error: API connector node not found: configure it in server.xml

Because of what it can be and how to solve the problem? On the computer and on the laptop, the server.xml files seem to have been received.

Comment: Do you use exactly the same Tomcat version on both systems?

Comment: Of course yes. But my computer has windows 10 and a laptop has windows 11. Is there a problem in this?

Comment: Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by reinstalling windows 10. Apparently there was some kind of incompatibility with Windows 11.